# webmaster tools information missing

Tags: schema, missing-data

so a 3-4 of months ago i clicked in google webmaster tools on "search appearance -> data highlighter and -> start highlighting". Everything was fine i had 10 items highlighted. I had 3 indexed pages, a ot of content keywords, 10 links to my website, a lot internal links. Two months ago, i deleted the highlighting from google webmaster tools and with the help from "google Structured Data Markup Helper" i added schema code to my website source. "Googles structured data testing tool" finds the items perfectly. 
The thing is that a week later, i got 1 indexed page, no information about links to my website, no information about internal links, no content keywords. When i try to highlight the  data again it popups a window where i should write a link which i want to highlight, but when i write my website i get "This URL could not be found in Google's index". I waited 2 months cause i thought it will be alright again, but no. 
Any idea what is happening ?

P.S. in "Search Traffic" i have no "manual actions"

Answer (score 0):

One thing, that i could imagine, is that you switched to https or from www.abc.de to abc.de. In this cases the Search console don´t works correct anymore. That is maybe your Problem. it would help if you could provide a Link.